# Strange behaviour of logging thread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have created the following program to create a logging thread and allow other threads to write into a shared buffer managed by this thread. Strangely though, if I do not include a write to the log in my `stopLog` function, the log is never closed and the thread does not terminate.

```
#include "log.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 128

static pthread_mutex_t logFileMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_mutex_t logInUse = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_cond_t emptyCond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_cond_t fullCond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
static int bufferIsEmpty;
static int bufferIsFull;
static char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
static int in;
static int out;
static int count;
static int stop;

void * logOutput(void * in) {
    stop = 0;
    bufferIsEmpty = 1;
    bufferIsFull = 0;
    char ch;
    FILE * f = fopen((char *)in, "a");
    if (NULL != f) {
        fprintf(f, "---------------- Log Opened ----------------\n");
        while (!stop) {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&logFileMutex);
            while (bufferIsEmpty)
                pthread_cond_wait(&emptyCond, &logFileMutex);
            ch = buffer[out++];
            out %= BUFFER_SIZE;
            if (--count == 0)
                bufferIsEmpty = 1;
            bufferIsFull = 0;
            fputc(ch, f);
            pthread_cond_signal(&fullCond);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&logFileMutex);
        }
        fprintf(f, "---------------- Log Closed ----------------\n");
        fflush(f);
        fclose(f);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening log file %s\n", (char *)in);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void writeToLog(char * str) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&logInUse);
    for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(str); i++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&logFileMutex);
        while (bufferIsFull)
            pthread_cond_wait(&fullCond, &logFileMutex);
        if (strlen(str) == i)
            buffer[in++] = '\n';
        else
            buffer[in++] = str[i];
        in %= BUFFER_SIZE;
        if (++count == (BUFFER_SIZE - 1))
            bufferIsFull = 1;
        bufferIsEmpty = 0;
        usleep(10);
        pthread_cond_signal(&emptyCond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&logFileMutex);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&logInUse);
}

void stopLog() {
    writeToLog("Stopping log...");
    stop = 1;
}
```

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but `logOutput` returns a `void *` but has no return statements.

Comment: @cormac-obrien That's fine - it's a pthread so pthread_exit takes care of the actual return

Comment: It's generally a good idea to provide one anyway -- if you don't have anything to return, just return `NULL`. Gets rid of a compiler warning if nothing else.

Comment: @cormac-obrien compiling with -Wall gives me no errors and no warnings on this piece of code :)

Comment: @cormac-obrien: If `pthread_exit()` is marked `_Noreturn` or equivalent, then the compiler is correct, and the thread exits with a null return value.  I get a variety of warnings from `gcc -O3   -g      -std=c11   -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror    -c logthr.c` (after removing the `#include "log.h"` line), but they're related to missing prototypes for the functions, and comparing `int` with `size_t`, not to the absence of a `return` in `logOutput()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the buffer is empty and `logOutput()` is blocked on `pthread_cond_wait()`, setting `stop = 1` is not going to wake it up.  It won't notice until the next time it wakes, and writing some log output accomplishes that.

As a variable shared between threads, `stop` also needs to be protected from unsynchronised accesses.

You can fix both these problems by changing the loop in `logOutput()` to

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&logFileMutex);
while (!stop)
{
    while (!stop && bufferIsEmpty)
        pthread_cond_wait(&emptyCond, &logFileMutex);

    while (!bufferIsEmpty)
    {
        ch = buffer[out++];
        out %= BUFFER_SIZE;
        if (--count == 0)
            bufferIsEmpty = 1;
        fputc(ch, f);
    }
    bufferIsFull = 0;
    pthread_cond_signal(&fullCond);
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&logFileMutex);
```

and changing `stopLog()` to:

```
void stopLog() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&logFileMutex);
    stop = 1;
    pthread_cond_signal(&emptyCond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&logFileMutex);
}
```

Now, when `stopLog()` is called, `logOutput()` will wake up, process any log messages that were sent at the same time as the stop and exit.